# How to read SMART stats of hard drives connected via Silicon Image Raid controller on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, sata, smart

I am using a PCI card in my Windows 10 (Enterprise) pc, which is correctly listed under Windows device management as "Silicon Image Sil 3114 SoftRaid 5 Controller". No RAID is enabled on the card. I am simply using it to connect more SATA HDD's than my motherboard allows. The connected drives work fine, except for SMART polling. CrystalDiskInfo 8.17.11 (latest) for instance detects all hard drives fine, but only lists temperature and SMART stats for the drives connected directly to my motherboard. Similar results in other SMART polling programs. The very same PCI card used to be installed in a Nas4Free (now Xigmanas) machine, which was able to report said stats fine.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.hdsentinel.com/compatibility_disk_controllers.php

I think HD Sentinel supports that controller, worth checking perhaps.

Comment: It does indeed. Thank you/bedankt, Joep!